# Stacked bootstrap modals: why in this codepen is the modal-backdrop inserted inside .modal?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

[This codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwZqdj) features an epic way to stack bootstrap modals. I'm trying to get it working in my app, but it seems that the `div.modal-backdrop` is getting inserted in the `body` in my app, whereas it's getting inserted inside the `.modal` element in this codepen.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="test-modal" data-modal-index="1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      [...]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer was that the codepen was using bootstrap 3.3.1 whereas I'm using 3.3.7. I wouldn't have expected such dramatic changes from such a small version change, but here we are.

I need functionality more like the old bootstrap, so now I'm thinking about copying the modal code from 3.3.1 as a kind of modal2 module.

**EDIT:** Tried that, didn't work super well. What I ended up doing to get the right functionality was making it so that multiple backdrops had an offset `z-index`, then custom-styled my specific modal:

```
.modal-backdrop + .modal-backdrop {
  z-index: 1038; /* instead of 1040 */
}

#outcomesModal.in.aside {
  z-index: 1039;
}
```

So now the modal, when put "aside" is between the two backdrops. Note that (different from the codepen) I had to apply the "aside" class to the `.modal`, not the `.modal-dialog`